# замена элементов одномерного массива Turbo Pascal

Tags: pascal, turbopascal

Задача:

> найти минимальное число в массиве, присвоить его значение к первому элементу массива; а вместо минимального числа записать 10.

Как найти минимальное и присвоить его первому элементу я додумался. Но как присвоить к заведомо неизвестному в массиве элементу 10 я не смог.

Вот код:

```
program test26;
var c:array[1..100] of real;
  i,n:integer;
  min,m:real;
begin
  writeln ('vvedite dlinnu massiva');
  readln (n);
  writeln ('vvedite el messiva');
  for i:=1 to n do
    readln (c[i]);
  min:=c[1];
  for i:=2 to n do
  if (min>=c[i]) then
  begin
    min:=c[i];
    c[1]:=min;
  end;
  writeln ('masiv= ');
  for i:=1 to n do
    write (c[i]:4:0);
  readln
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
program test26;
var 
  c:array[1..100] of real;
  i,n,index:integer;
begin
  index:=1;
  writeln ('vvedite dlinnu massiva');
  readln (n);
  writeln ('vvedite el messiva');
  for i:=1 to n do
    readln (c[i]);
  for i:=1 to n do
    if (c[index]>c[i]) then index:=i;
  c[1]:=c[index];
  c[index]:=10;     
  writeln ('masiv= ');
  for i:=1 to n do
    write (c[i]:4:0);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, но как это работает????? я понимаю что индекс это порядковый номер в массиве чисел, или это не так... но как оно работает я не понимаю. Можете объяснить почему в c забили индекс , как он работает и почему тут именно такой знак c[index]>c[i] ??? очень хочу понять

Comment: @Pulse все предельно просто, у нас есть массив, нам надо найти минимальное число и заменить его, зачем искать само число если можно найти где именно в массиве оно хранится =) это тут и происходит, мы ищем местоположение минимального числа а не само число

Comment: а чуууууууууточку подробнее? например полностью. То что для опытного кодера элементарно, для 17 летнего студента жесть

Comment: Полностью? не не не =) если есть строки которых непонимаете - запросто объясню, но писать комментарии к каждой строке кода из примитивных операторов - выше моих сил. `index` - номер элемента в массиве. `c[index]` - получить число под номером `index`

Comment: понял, ладно тогда.  Спасибо. Уже второй раз помогаете

Answer (score 2):

Кроме значения минимума, нужно ещё запоминать его индекс.

Заменять первый элемент и минимальный достаточно один раз

```
min := c[1];
imin := 1;
for i:=2 to n do
   if (min > c[i]) then begin
       min:=c[i];
       imin = i;
   end;
```

Comment: как это записать в программе? я не до конца понял

Comment: Как запомнить - я добавил.